# Whether a non-zero module can have a zero socle?

Tags: modules, socle

Let $M$ be a module. Then $soc(M)=\sum\{N\leq M| \text{$N$ is a simple submodule of $M$}\}=\cap\{L\leq M| \text{$L$ is essential in $M$}\} $. I don't know whether a non-zero module can have zero socle? Who can give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of **finite-dimensional representations**, you always have a nonzero socle. *Hint:* Consider subrepresentations of minimal dimension. **In general**, it's not true. *Hint:* Consider torsion-free modules over integral domains, e.g. over $k[x]$.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Or as an alternative easier example for the latter, the integers as a module over themselves (though of course this is no longer an algebra over a field).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yep :)

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft. Thank you very much for your example. rad M=soc M=0 if we regard the integer $\mathbb{Z}=M$ as a module over themselve.