# Reducible modules

Tags: representation-theory

Let's $M\not=0$ be a reducible $R$-module, where $R$ is not necessarily semisimple. By definition, there is a submodule of $M$, let's denote it by $S$, where $S\not=0,M$. However, we don't know if $S$ is irreducible. Can we always find an irreducible submodule? I was thinking of using Zorn's lemma.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206616/whether-a-non-zero-module-can-have-a-zero-socle/2206623#2206623

Comment: Thank you! So, if I have finite dimensional representations, the answer to my question is yes.

Comment: Yes, er more generally if you consider Artinian modules.